# How to access ProXPN's settings?

Tags: software, vpn, utilities, menu-bar, 3rd-party

I installed ProXPN on my Mac and successfully used it. It installs an icon in the menu bar which you can use to enable and disable the application. I was messing around with the settings and clicked on the option which said something like "show icon near spotlight icon in the menu bar". After restarting my computer, I no longer see the icon in the menu bar. When I try to launch the application from my Applications folder, it doesn't seem like it's doing anything.

How can I access the program or its settings?

Comment: I have the same problem, proXPN won't open at all, I've tried everything conventional and nothing worked. By the way I can't delete it and re-download it because I live in China and the proXPN website has been censored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that when you launch ProXPN and you are not connected to a wireless network, it does not launch.

You must first connect to the wireless network, and only then launch ProXPN.

If you have set up ProXPN to launch at start up, it will work as long as your computer is set to automatically connect to a network, which will probably happen before ProXPN is launched automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on my mac, and all this seems to do is to not place the icon next to the spotlight icon.  When I relaunched proXPN, it placed the icon on the left side of all icons on the top. At first, I couldn't see it either but that was due to the app I had open having too many menu items taking up real estate - I switched to finder and voila!  There the proXPN icon was.